# Cannot print multiple countplot charts based on different features in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, seaborn, subplot

I am using the Titanic dataset shown below:

[image]

I want to create a count plot using Seaborn for a few different feature columns.  Below is my attempted code:

```
col_list = ['sex', 'class', 'embark_town']

for i in col_list:
    print (i)
    
    feature_plot = sns.countplot(x=df[i])
    print (feature_plot)
```

Unfortunately, my output only produces the chart for the last column in my col_list (not the two previous ones).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that seaborn plots on top of the las figure

try to create a new figure

```py
col_list = ['sex', 'class', 'embark_town']

for i in col_list:
    print (i)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    feature_plot = sns.countplot(x=df[i], ax=ax)
    print (feature_plot)
    plt.show()
```